# Does the Emerald Potion know when the drinker is scooping it up and throw it away or scooping it up and drinking it?

Tags: harry-potter

Does the Emerald Potion know when the drinker is scooping it up and throw it away or scooping it up and drinking it?

Dumbledore in the books said this line:

> “Oh yes.” Dumbledore peered more closely into the basin. Harry saw his face reflected, upside down, in the smooth surface of the green potion. “But how to reach it? This potion cannot be penetrated by hand, Vanished, parted, scooped up, or siphoned away, nor can it be Transfigured, Charmed, or otherwise made to change
>   its nature.”

But Dumbledore scooped it up first before drinking it. Does this mean the Emerald Potion knows when it is being scooped up to be thrown away and when it is being scooped up to be drunk?

Comment: Dumbledore certainly thought so. And he knows a lot more about magic than we do

Comment: I have been pondering this same thing pretty much ever since *HBP* came out. I'd love to get a definitive answer.

Comment: In my opinion, it isn't the potion, but instead a charm placed in the recipient. But it is hard to give a definitive answer when there's no canon answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no canon answer we can only guess. My best guess is: there is a finite amount of potion. This potion always seeks its way back to the basin after a short amount of time or whenever spilled. The only thing that keeps it from returning is the body / stomach of a (living) person.

So: you need to drink all of the potion to prevent it from getting back.

On the other hand that would mean: as soon as the person who drank it dies or otherwise gets rid of the potion (better not think about that possibility), it again returns to its original place...

But again: as there is no canonical answer I know of this is only a guess of mine.